# Parse.com Swift Reset Badge for Push Notifications

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm using the last version of the Parse Library and the last version of Xcode 6.3.2 The application receive Notifications just right and when the application became active it reset the badge locally but in the next Notification the badge just ignores the 0 value for the badge.

The code:

```
        if (currentInstallation.badge != 0) {
            self.reloadInfo = true
            currentInstallation.badge = 0
            currentInstallation.saveEventually()
        } else {
            self.reloadInfo = false
        }
```

Does not work, neither

```
currentInstallation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
currentInstallation.badge = 0
currentInstallation.saveEventually()
```

Any ideas of what can be wrong ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you checked your Parse.com server and checked the installation table to make sure it's actually reset to 0?

Comment: It's not reset, everything is very weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was just a mess with the provisioning profile, the Parse Installation database, it is just solved.

Thanks.